# GPU JS loop works incorrect

Tags: javascript, gpu

I wrote this JS for CPU before which works correcly. Now need to do it over GPU; but inner loop doesnt work correctly; result canvas always in grays, why?

```
const dist = 4
const target = document.getElementById("target")
const gpu = new GPU()
const conv = function (cnv,dist,w,h) {
    const px = this.thread.x
    const py = this.thread.y
    var pixel = cnv[py][px]
    var pixel1 = cnv[py][px]
    var score = -1
    for (var cy=-dist; cy <= dist; cy++) {
        for (var cx=-dist; cx <= dist; cx++) {
            const x = px+cx
            const y = py+cy
            if (x >= 0 && x < w && y >= 0 && y < h) {
                var pixel2 = cnv[py][px]
                const error = Math.sqrt(
                    Math.pow((pixel1[0]*255)-(pixel2[0]*255),2)+
                    Math.pow((pixel1[1]*255)-(pixel2[1]*255),2)+
                    Math.pow((pixel1[2]*255)-(pixel2[2]*255),2))
                if (score < error) {
                    score = error
                    pixel= pixel2
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.color(
        ((pixel[0]*255)-(pixel1[0]*255)+128)/255,
        ((pixel[1]*255)-(pixel1[1]*255)+128)/255,
        ((pixel[2]*255)-(pixel1[2]*255)+128)/255
    )
}
const kernel = gpu.createKernel(conv)
    .setConstants({ width: target.width, height: target.height })
    .setGraphical( true )
    .setOutput([ target.width, target.height ])
kernel(target,dist,target.width,target.height)
document.body.appendChild(kernel.canvas)
```